# How to take several photos and display them in an imageview?

Tags: java, android, image, android-imageview

My problem may seem simple but I'm really starting to despair with this... I am currently trying to take several photos and implement them directly afterwards in an imageview. Currently, I am able to do it with one image but not with two and even less with three. I've tested loops and forks but I haven't found the trick yet... These photos are then stored on firebase to be recovered by users afterwards. In the order of my code I show you my different functions.
My request is therefore simple, someone would have is a trick to remedy to worry?

The first function displays the result on my activity. That is to say the image captured on my image and the second function is for storing the image on Firebase Storage :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PICTURE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        File imgFile = new  File(pictureFilePath);
        if(imgFile.exists())            {
            image.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(imgFile)); 
        }
    }
}


private void addToCloudStorage() {
        File f = new File(pictureFilePath);
        Uri picUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
        final String cloudFilePath = deviceIdentifier +picUri.getLastPathSegment();

        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        String userId = user.getUid();

        FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference storageRef = firebaseStorage.getReference();
        StorageReference uploadeRef = storageRef.child(cloudFilePath);

        uploadeRef.child(userId).putFile(picUri).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Vos photos n'ont pas été tranférées sur les serveurs. Veuillez réessayer !");
            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                Toast.makeText(DescriptionLogement.this,
                        "Vos photos ont été déposées avec succès !",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
}
```

The REQUEST_PICTURE_CAPTURE is equal to 6.

```
static final int REQUEST_PICTURE_CAPTURE = 6;
```

Comment: "I am able to do it with one image but not with two and even less with three" -- you have not explained what your problem is. You have explained what you want, but not what is not working for you.

Comment: I would like to be able to take 3 images "in a row" and put them in my imageview. For the moment I can do it with one and not with several!

Comment: "I would like to be able to take 3 images "in a row" and put them in my imageview". Have you considered using Recyclerview with gridlayoutmanager?

Comment: Not at all! Any specific way to use it? I'll look into it and see what I can do.